# Mix .NetCore 3 and .NetFramework in same solution

Tags: .net-core, .net-4.5

So im porting over our API from .Net Framework 4.5 to .Net Core 3 and im having some problems with the older projects that reference SqlDatabase. My Soulution has the new .Net Core 3 API and it depends on old projects that are written in VB.Net(.Net Framework 4.5). I am having problems using some of the old projects because there are failing on `new SqlDatabase(...)`.

I think this is caused because the solution gets compiled as .Net Core and doesnt contain the write dlls for the .Net Framework dlls?

```
MySolution
    - NewAPI Project(.Net Core 3)
    - Old VB Project #1(.Net Framework 4.5)
    - Old VB Project #2(.Net Framework 4.5)
    - Old VB Project #3(.Net Framework 4.5) <- This does all the SQL db work and gets called by the NewAPI project.
    - etc...
```

When i do a dotnet restore i get a few warnings that state:

```
`warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll' 3.1.0
' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2
, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Versio
n=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.
NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your pro
ject.`

`warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.dll' 3.1.0'
was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2,
.NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=
v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NE
TCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your proje
ct.`

`warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder.dll 3.1.0' was resto
red using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFrame
work,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .
NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,
Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`
```

The error that gets caught from the old project is `The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database' threw an exception.`

Comment: Do you mean you reference your VB Full Framework libraries from your .NET Core application? That won't work.

Comment: @nvoigt Yes that is correct. So is there no way to use the old libraries from .Net Core?

Comment: No. .NET Core can reference .NET Standard and .NET Core. **Not** .NET Framework. You could communicate over other means though, just as you would normally communicate across languages. HTTP, TCP, Message Queues. But you canot reference the assemblies directly.

Comment: In my opinion you should build a .Net Standard middleware/library to handle the communications between .net core 3 and .net framework.

Comment: @PedroBrito, do you have a link to any type of tutorial on this?

Comment: There is no concrete tutorial, to build this project is the same as building a .net core or .net framework application. You can read [this](https://www.ben-morris.com/sharing-libraries-between-net-core-and-net-framework-applications/). But you have to think that this new project will be the bridge between the .netframework and the .net core 3.